# trying to enter with custom price but strategy.entry limit is not working

Tags: pine-script, limit

I have a code that needs to create signals for buy and sell. I am currently using `strategy.entry`, and because this function triggers at the `close` or `open`, I want to change it to a custom entry price like `close * 1.001`. This way, it will trigger at a slightly higher price, and the buy should be guaranteed.

I am using this code:

```
buyhere = close * 1.0005
strategy.entry("LONG", strategy.long, limit=buyhere)
```

I plot buyhere, and it looks good, showing exactly what I want. However, neither signals nor alerts are executing the buy at that limit price.

What could be the issue here?